# How to compute the np.insert "obj" parameter?

Tags: numpy

I currently get the following input:

1. An array "x"
2. A list of indices where zeros should be after scattering x into a larger array.

Does anyone happen to have any quick code that computes the "obj" variable corresponding to this.

Example: `x = [1,2,3,4]` and I want to turn it into `x = [1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4]`. The input I have is where the zeros are supposed to be in the resulting array, i.e.

```
 ([1,2,3,4], [2, 3, 5]) => [1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4]
```

How do I compute given an array "x" and the indices where the resulting zeros should be the "obj" parameter that puts the zeros at these indices?

Comment: Shouldnt that be : `=> [1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4]`?

Comment: @Divakar: Yes. Typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the new object with ranged differences, like so -

```
In [60]: x
Out[60]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [61]: idx
Out[61]: [2, 3, 5]

In [62]: new_obj = idx - np.arange(len(idx))

In [63]: np.insert(x,new_obj,0)
Out[63]: array([1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4])
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear enough. I know how to implement this myself without using np.insert. However, I need to compute the parameter for np.insert that does this, because a library function that I call uses np.insert under the hood and needs the indices in the format it expects.

Comment: In other words, for the particular example that I have I need a function that on input [2,3,5] returns [2, 2, 3].